# How to draw a graph of a cumulative number from a file in R?

Tags: r, draw

I need to draw a graph of the cumulative number of deaths in some countries from a file containing the cumulative amount of deaths by countries in the world from COVID-19.

This is the file we got - "time_series_covid19_deaths_global.csv"
I'm pretty new in R so I don't really know how even to start, I would love to get some help.

Comment: Your question is very broad and should be more specific when making a post and include discussion of what you've tried already. This said: you must first read the file into R before you can see the data or manipulate it. See the read.csv() function: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.6.2/topics/read.table

Answer (score 0):

You can make a graph by plotting certain points in a simple way:

```
# Here is a daily deaths graph from the past 10 days in Canada using a line graph.
daily_deaths_from_canada <- c(89, 95, 82, 56, 98, 81, 114, 82, 89, 93)
plot(daily_deaths_from_canada)
```

If you want to learn more, I suggest look at [this page](https://sites.harding.edu/fmccown/r/).